# Do we need any more [programming] [practice]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blacklist-request

The first tag has been recreated multiple times, while the second is likely a variation of [best-practice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice), which was previously removed and temporarily blacklisted.  They are about as useless as [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review) and may still likely come back until the tag-creation privilege increases to 1500 rep.

Comment: YES PLEASE! BURN THEM!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) - that is what the site is about.  Are we going to tag every question with it?

[practice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) - we all need practice.  On a serious note, I don't see how this tag adds any value to the site either.  Perhaps if someone created a tag wiki I would understand it better, but I have a hard time even seeing where this would be used.